# Retrive data with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pg-query

I am having a project using PHP and Postgres. I tried to write a function to get all infomation from one class required from user's input. Below is the version does not work. The commented part is the one that did pretty well but I need to put it into function for reusing target.

```
function getInfoClass($classID) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Class
                  WHERE ID = '{$classID}';";
        $result = pg_query($db, $query);
        return  pg_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

$row = getInfoClass($_SESSION["classID"]);
echo $row['id'];

//$query = "SELECT * FROM Class
//            WHERE ID = '{$_SESSION["classID"]}';";
//$result = pg_query($db, $query);

//while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//  echo $row['id'];
//}
```

Comment: $db isn't defined in the scope of the function. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: @OfirBaruch it should be, @SonTung  you must write in the head of the function `global $db;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be running into scope issues here. Make sure to read the php error_log since I'm pretty sure that $db is not declared within the function. If you are using classes and its defined within the class then try $this->db. If not using classes, add it to the parameters as &$db (byReference).